# Storing the parsed JSON values in CSV by using JMeter Bean shell or BSF post processor

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

I have a API returning json response. I need to parse the JSON array to get those data from it and store it in the CSV file. These things are need to be done as the part of the JMeter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following tutorial is applicable for you http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/FFWTutorials

Comment: I think there is standard jmeter solution based on sample_variables.